# PLSQL: function that return any column of choice

Tags: function, plsql

to make as simple as possible, Instead of creating a couple of functions like:

```
get_emp_name( 123 );
get_emp_age( 123 );
```

...

I want to create a plsql function that I Can specify which column I would like to be filtered by like this:

```
get_emp(employee.column_name, employee.ID )
```

**example:**

```
get_emp(employee.name,123); -- it will return 'John'
get_emp(employee.age,123): -- it will return 40
```

this will make it easy for me to create one function that will return any column of choice, but I couldn't create it in plsql oracle, so can you guys help me to create it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not exactly what you want, but perhaps it would be better for you to create function returning record

```
function get_emp(p_employee_id in employee.id%type) return employee%rowtype is
   l_emp employee%rowtype ;
begin
   select e.* into l_emp
     from employee e
    where e.id = p_employee_id;

   return l_emp;
end;
```

You could then get specific fields this way:

```
get_emp(123).name
get_emp(123).age
```

Here is a working example:

```
SQL> create table employee (id number primary key, name varchar2(30), age number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into employee values (1, 'Smith', 28);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into employee values (2, 'Jones', 30);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into employee values (3, 'Brown', 34);

1 row created.

SQL> create function get_emp(p_employee_id in employee.id%type) return employee%rowty
  2     l_emp employee%rowtype ;
  3  begin
  4     select e.* into l_emp
  5       from employee e
  6      where e.id = p_employee_id;
  7
  8     return l_emp;
  9  end;
 10  /

Function created.

SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line('Name = ' || get_emp(1).name);
  3    dbms_output.put_line('Age = ' || get_emp(1).age);
  4  end;
  5  /
Name = Smith
Age = 28
```

Of course the last PL/SQL block is not very efficient because it calls the function (and therefore the query) twice. More efficient version would be:

```
declare
  l_emp employee%rowtype;
begin
  l_emp := get_emp(1);
  dbms_output.put_line('Name = ' || l_emp.name);
  dbms_output.put_line('Age = ' || l_emp.age);
end;
/
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I tried to do exactly what you said and I got this error: "ORA-00902: Invalid datatype". so if you can help me more I'll thankful to you.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Perhaps the complete example will help you.

Comment: If I try to call your function through a regular "Select" statement it'll not work and I'll get the same error I told you about, but If I use dbms_output.put_line it'll work. can you explain to me why is that happening.

Comment: Shortly: because employee%rowtype is only a PL/SQL type and as such cannot be used in pure SQL. You would have to return object type to use it in SQL. By the way: why do you need to use it in select statement? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry for not replying fast, I just finished my vacation :), the reason I want this is because I work in data warehouse, and we often receive different ad hock reports, so this PL/SQLfunction I asked about will make it easy for me to get the columns I want instead of joining a lot of tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using dynamic sql.

```
function get_emp (v_column in varchar2, v_id in number)
  return varchar2
is
  v_sql varchar2(4000);
  v_value varchar2(4000);
begin

   v_sql := 'select ' || v_column || ' into :x from employee where id = ' || v_id;
   execute immediate v_sql into v_value;

  return v_value;

end get_emp;
```

Comment: You should try to explain your code when you post it. Also, indenting starts at 4 spaces, not 2. Please edit this and look at the preview to make sure the code displays properly.

Comment: in order to prevent SQL-Injection, you should use bind variables instead of concatenating. Better write your code like this:      v_sql := 'select ' || v_column || ' from employee where id = :1';
     execute immediate v_sql into v_value using v_id;